# Is there a problem with Beamer in the latest MiKTeX update?

Tags: beamer, miktex

This is about MiKTeX Revision 2.9.6360.

Immediately after the latest MiKTeX update, my Beamer files stopped compiling.  When i tried to compile a file that had been working fine I got a Package installation popup saying:

```
tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty

Is missing.  It is part of the following package

beamer
```

So i clicked to have it installed.  All that achieved is that i got an error message

```
! LaTeX error: File 'beamerbasemodes.sty' not found
```

I repeated this a few times with minor changes to the file, and then went to the MiKTeX Package Manager to see what parts of Beamer are installed.  It said none were.

Either the update had removed Beamer, or the attempt to install beamerbasemodes on the fly had done it.  So I reinstalled it by hand.  In fact i did this several times in various ways.  It made one difference.  Sometimes the problem package was identified as

translator.sty

In case it would help, I ran Update FNDB and restarted my machine.  Each time I installed Beamer, the Package Manager then reported that Beamer was installed.

But when I tried to compile the file, the same things happened all over.   And when i went back to the MiKTeX Package Manager it reported Beamer is not installed.

Is Beamer now out of date?  Or is this a problem on the new update?  Is there a simple fix i can use?

Comment: We've moved `translator` out as a separate package on CTAN: it may have to be installed by hand ...

Comment: Yes, that did it.

Comment: @JosephWright Could you write a short answer, so that duplicates of this questions can be marked as such?

Comment: @samcarter I'm not really sure that's the issue: it was more an observation. `translator` has nothing to do with `beamerbasemodes`!

Comment: @JosephWright Is this possible: something in the update removed the Beamer I had been using (I was using it just minutes before I did the update) but did not install the new version of Beamer and did not install translator.  Then when I installed the new version of Beamer it naturally lacked translator and so i still had to install it.

Comment: I had no problems with a minimal beamer example. Synchronize your package manager (user and admin) in the  menu repositories.

Comment: I am experiencing this problem with TeXMaker. I am behind the latest version, but I just updated and the problem persists.

Answer (score 21):

The problem disappeared when I used the MiKTeX Package Manager to install Beamer and translator, used Refresh FNDB, and restarted my machine.

Experience with a second machine shows the latest update indeed replaces the old Beamer with one that does not have translator in it, so I had to install translator separately using the MiKTeX Package Manager.  When I did that immediately then the new Beamer stayed installed and there was no need to Refresh FNDB or restart the machine.

But for some reason when I tried to let MiKTeX install translator on the fly it not only failed, but erased my Beamer.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! To provide insight into my problem, I had never used Beamer before so it was not installed. That's about all.

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem for me. I am using the latest Texmaker and Miktex. The presentation uses the metropolis theme.

Comment: Colin, in what directory did you install the translator.sty? in the beamer dir?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I did it by the MiKTeX Package Manager so I did not know what directory it went into.  But that problem was 17 months ago.