# How to fix “LaTeX Error: File `beamerbasemodes.sty' not found”?

Tags: beamer, packages, installing, miktex-update

I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 64-bit with texmaker. When I tried to compile a beamer presentation, I get a dialog window like this
[image]

I select "Install" and then get the following error:

! LaTeX Error: File `beamerbasemodes.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.

What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yu may, from MiKTeX Package Manager (admin mode), first uninstall beamer, then re-install it.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404218/is-there-a-problem-with-beamer-in-the-latest-miktex-update

Comment: I would at first synchronize the repositories (menu repositories in the package manager (admin + user version)).