# LaTeX Error: File `beamerbasemodes.sty' not found

Tags: beamer

! LaTeX Error: File `beamerbasemodes.sty' not found. I have this error in latex. How can I risolve it?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404218/is-there-a-problem-with-beamer-in-the-latest-miktex-update

Comment: Did you try to uninstall beamer and then follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404272/36296 ?